# Android FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON Fragment Nav Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, screen, drawer

I use the Navigation Drawer, and in a Fragment that is open I want to have the active screen.

I use:

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But this thing light up the screen in every fragment of the navigation drawer. How can I get the screen active only in one fragment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When each fragment is selected from the navigation drawer, for those you want to have the screen kept on do:

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

for those you what to have normal screen dimming and turn-off do:

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Another method for controlling the screen that is more convenient in some cases is [View.setKeepScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn(boolean)).  It can be called on any view.  It will keep the screen on as long as the view is visible.

You can also control screen-on with the [android:keepScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:keepScreenOn) attribute in the layout XML.